# How to show only compiling errors in Eclipse's editors?

Tags: java, eclipse, validation, compiler-errors, warnings

I participate in development very big project. Project consist on many(more than 30) Eclipse projects. Every project uses specific Eclipse setiings for validation(for example boxing/unboxing - error for these settings).

I want to see **only compilation errors**. I know this way:

click on project settings and select  ignore error/warnings for all lines.

But for 30 project -it is very big and stupid work. Maybe are there way - faster ?

Answer (score 1):

As +Sam Yonnou all but said, you need to either actually *turn off* the warnings you don't care about by setting the Compiler to ignore those things, or go to the Annotations preference page and disable their presentation entirely:

[image: Annotations preference page with the Warning annotation type selected.]

This page will affect **all text editors**, though.

Comment: I think - it is not bad variant. But I see many warnings like errors. This fix don't resolve problem enirely.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by seeing "many warnings like errors." Problem severities are one or the other (or Info).

Comment: if go to Errors / Warnings - there are selector with 3 states(warning, error and ignore)

Comment: Yes, there you can ignore the ones you don't care for.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse if you're worried about the warnings coming up in the Problems View, you can click the little down arrow on the top right of the Problems View, and select Show then All Errors, which will hide the warnings in the Problems View. As for hiding the messages in the source code editor, I don't know.

Comment: *As for hiding the messages in the source code editor* - it is main problem

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, then you can fix this by going to

`Window > Preferences > Java > compiler > Errors / Warnings`

and adjusting the settings there to fit your needs.

Comment: project can use common settings and project specific settings. your variant works for projects which don't use specific settings.

Comment: Yeah if you have projects with their own specific settings you'll need to fix their errors / warnings settings individually. Assuming the projects are checked out on your local machine and you aren't committing Eclipse projects settings to the repository, you can just uncheck the "Enable project specific settings" for all of the projects you want to use the unified (workspace) errors / warnings settings.